# Viewport size, huge whitespace new on responsive site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an existing fixed-width desktop site, and the client wants no changes to the existing desktop layout whatsoever, and they want it to be "responsive".

### The Problem:

When viewed on a phone (my android, anyhow), the 'mobile' site loads as expected.  However, if you touch, move, scroll, etc, or happen to "zoom out", there is a huge amount of whitespace like this:

[image]

### Background:

For the record: The new specs for the "mobile" view contains some new content, new menu options, etc., which don't always correlate consistently with the existing content.

So, my approach has been to add a css class to elements I want to keep, then use jQuery.clone(), .append(), and appendTo() to re-use as much of the existing content as possible, moving elements into my new "mobile scaffold":

```
$('.mobile-header').appendTo($('#PH_mobile_header'));
$('.mobile-content').appendTo($('#PH_mobile_content'));
$('.mobile-footer').appendTo($('#PH_mobile_footer'));
```

The simplified scaffold:

```
<div id= "PH_mobile_wrapper" class="mobile-wrapper mobile visible-xs">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div id="main" class= "col-xs-12">
          <div id="PH_mobile_header" class="visible-xs">
            <!-- HEADER -->
          </div>
          <div id="PH_mobile_content" class="container visible-xs">
            <!-- CONTENT -->
          </div>
          <div id="PH_mobile_footer" class="visible-xs">
            <!-- FOOTER -->
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also rely on 2 sections of a new LESS stylesheet to tweak a few things.  For example:

```
//DESKTOP:
@media(min-width:768px){

  h1{
    font-size: 2em !important;
  }

  body{
    background-color: @ltgrey;
  }

  .navbar{
    width:1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border-right: solid black 1px;
  }

  .mobile{
    display: none;
  }
}

//MOBILE:
@media(max-width:768px){

  li.inverse{
    background-color: @dkgrey;
    color: white;

    a{
      color: white;
      &:hover, &:focus{
        background-color: @olacred;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

For the record, I'm using bootstrap 3.0 and php if that's relevant.  I just mention that in case bootstrap is related to this somehow.

I started with the standard

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and i've tried

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1">`

Also read about CSS @viewport, but it doesn't seem to do the trick either.

I've even tried explicitly doing this at the end of my stylesheet:

```
#layout_wrapper, #layout_container,.dashboard_home_highlights,
.collapse-wrapper,#alpha,#beta,.dashboard_col_1_rotonator, 
.orbit > a > img, .orbit > a{
  // display: none !important;
  max-width:300px !important;
}
```

blah.

### So the questions are:

a. How do I fix this "viewport" issue, and b. is this all-around approach OK?

EDIT: Here is a partial demo: http://myapp.gristech.com/demo/viewport

Grrr...I have failed to completely reproduce the entire problem, but here you can see the approach, and one bug: if you pull this up on a phone, then zoom in, the text correctly squeezes into the view. Then, zoom back out... the text does NOT expand again as it should, leaving extra whitespace so to speak, and scrolling down is thereafter "wobblely". This is kind of what I think is going on on a larger scale in the full project- since the 1000px site loads 'first', then the 'layout viewport' is still 1000px. thank you so much for your time & effort

Comment: would be better to see it live

Comment: can you provide a link to the example, or a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: and why are you using jQuery to set stuff up for mobile? Bootstrap 3 has `.hidden-xs`, `.visible-xs`, `.hidden-md`, `.visible-md`, etc

Comment: Additionally, are you sure you want to have that `.navbar { width:1000; }` for `@media(min-width:768px)`? Sounds like you may have some users experiencing scrolling issues for no apparent reason

Comment: Oh wow... I just read what you are actually trying to achieve here.... It sounds like you should either add a new folder (say m.yoursite.com) to redirect mobile devices with a bootstrap version of the site, or duplicate content and hide on xm and xs devices the regular version, and hide the bootstrap version on md and up... I have an idea of what the issue is, but hard to tell without the site to look at...

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira I do use the .hidden/visible-xs, etc., but there are many classes to update in the existing code... besides: the hidden-xs for example is just a wrapper for ".responsive-invisibility()" within a media query, which points to mixins.less, and ultimately just "display: block !important;".  In other words, those utility classes are convenient, but I think any display:block !important does the same thing.

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira as for the navbar width and the overall approach... the goal is NOT to make a whole new mobile site - and the entire existing site is 1000px.  In other words, it was like that when I got it, and that is one example of putting it back the way it was pre-bootstrap.  Also, there is a lot going on in the header - queries and sessions etc... so duplicating it and maintaining a totally seperate version... yuck.  I'm trying to arrange a live recreation for you, bear with me...  What if I try to use javascript to only insert the bs files, based on media query?

Comment: You can probably try that... but it might be a pain to make the website stay the same while at the same time having the classes all set up so that you just add the css files. But of course that would likely depend on how the website is layed out and if you wont have many conflicting classes

Comment: Grrr...I have failed to completely reproduce the entire problem, but [here](http://myapp.gristech.com/demo/viewport) you can see the approach, and one bug: if you pull this up on a phone, then zoom in, the text correctly squeezes into the view.  then, zoom back out... the text does not expand again as it should, leaving extra whitespace so to speak, and scrolling down is thereafter "wobblely".  This is kind of what I think is going on on a larger scale in the full project- since the 1000px site loads 'first', then the 'layout viewport' is still 1000px.  thank you so much for your time & effort

Comment: I also thought to wrap the entire old stylesheet in @media(min-width:768px){} - but that in itself does not work.  I finally got it to work with the combination of forcing EVERY old fixed-width element explicitly to something small like 300px, combined with 'user-scalable=no'.